# P-value distribution under alternative hypothesis is stochastically smaller than uniform

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, p-value

During a lesson at university, we ran this simulation to assess the fact that p-value distribution under alternative hypothesis is stochastically smaller than the uniform distribution.

So suppose we want to make an F-test for a linear regression (joint nullity of parameters)

```
n=10
p=3
beta=c(1,2,0) #beta_2=2,null hypothesis of test f is false
sim<-function(n,p)
{
x<-cbind(1,matrix(runif(n*(p-1)),ncol=p-1))
y<-x%*%beta+rnorm(n)
X<-as.data.frame(x)
anova(lm(y~1),lm(y~.,X))
#prendo il p value
pval<-anova(lm(y~1),lm(y~.,X))$'Pr(>F)'[2]
return (pval)
}

res<-replicate(100,sim(10,3))
hist(res)
plot(ecdf(res))
curve(punif,0,1,add=T,col="red")
```

and I obtain this graph

[image]

Could anyone explain (and maybe provide a little proof) of the above statement:

> p-value distribution under alternative hypothesis is stochastically smaller than the uniform distribution

Comment: For this question, I recommend: Hung, HMJ (1997). [The Behavior of the P-Value When the Alternative Hypothesis is True](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2533093.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A30ec764c1289a7066484b9db035be15a). * Biometrics, 53*, 1, pp. 11-22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that this is a self-study question, so I will not give a full explanation, but rather some hints

Assuming you know

- What "stochastically smaller" means (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering))
- And you are able to interpret the difference of two cumulative distribution such as in the figure above above (note that the red line is the uniform, maybe it helps to look at the histogram as well)

Then the answer should be obvious.

Side note: excellent that you do these kind of simulations in class, I think this is very instructive.

Comment: Ok i realize that it was a dumb question. Anyway is there any proof for that fact without using any simulation? Is that a general fact that holds always? thanks

Comment: You want to proof that ANY alternative hypothesis is stochastically smaller than a uniform under a correctly specified hypothesis test?

Comment: Is it something impossible?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. My intuition would be that it should be possible to construct a test statistic that produces a counterexample, but then we wouldn't call it a valid hypothesis test. Would be a good question to ask.

Comment: @Marco It's not impossible; biased tests exist, and are very widely used

Comment: @Glen_b - but does bias not usually refer to not properly calibrated type I error? Here, the question would be specifically about an alternative hypothesis that has a higher chance to "produce" the observed data that the true hypothesis.

Comment: I just thought an example where I encountered this (approximately) are likelihoods for highly nonlinear state-space models. In this case, it seems as if the true model can be dominated by alternative models in terms of likelihoods, the same should be true for p-values I guess. See appendix of Hartig, F. & Dormann, C. F. Does model-free forecasting really outperform the true model? Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 2013, 110, E3975, https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.3544

Comment: @Florian No; "improperly calibrated" type I error would be called conservative tests or anti-conservative tests. Bias in hypothesis testing is when you have lower rejection rates under some alternative than under the null. These are *really* common in practice, however.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for the clarification - do you by any chance have a reference for this - I couldn't find anything with google, and it would be nice to have something to point to for the future.

Comment: Sorry -it's not quite clear what you're after. Do you seek an example of a test where there's a lower rejection rate under some alternative than the null? \[If it's about the definition of a biased test, see for example Casella & Berger *Statistical Inference*, p364,
Definition 8.3.4 (which gives the definition of an unbiased test), or see [here](https://turing.une.edu.au/~stat354/notes/node80.html) for example; a biased test is simply a test that's not unbiased. I expect Casella & Berger should be sufficient but there are other references for that\]

Comment: @Glen_b yes, exactly that, thanks, and sorry, now I realize that searching for "unbiased tests" would have produced suitable references.